# Pass data between event handlers in collection

Tags: events, ms-access, vba

I have a collection of event handlers of extended textboxes that handle the click event.  On a click of any textbox in a column the event handler will unlock every textbox in that column by calling its form name and then sets a variable with an identifing variable in the active handler.  Is there a way to set this identify variable inother handler objects from inside the handler active handler.  Would i have to pass the collection by reference to each handler object to accomplish this or is there a way that I can set and event to pass the data between the objects?

Here is the code to my event handler object

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit
Private WithEvents TC_txtbox As TextBox
Private m_Day As String
' Set the textbox so that its events will be handled
Public Property Set TextBox(ByVal m_tcTxtBox As access.TextBox)
    Set TC_txtbox = m_tcTxtBox
    TC_txtbox.OnClick = "[Event Procedure]"
    TC_txtbox.Enabled = True
    TC_txtbox.Locked = True
    TC_txtbox.BackColor = 16777215
End Property
' Handle and onClick event of the textboxes
Private Sub TC_txtbox_Click()
    ' Find out the controls that where click
    If Not m_Day = "" Then
        ' Highlight text inside text box
        Form_TimeCard.ActiveControl.SelStart = 0
        Form_TimeCard.ActiveControl.SelLength = Len(Form_TimeCard.ActiveControl.Text)
    Else ' Day has not been set enable text boxes
        m_Day = Form_TimeCard.ActiveControl.Tag

        Dim ctl As Control
        For Each ctl In Form_TimeCard.Controls
            If m_Day = ctl.Tag Then
                ctl.Locked = False
                ctl.BackColor = 65535
            End If
        Next ctl

        ' Save button is now visible
        Form_TimeCard.but_save.Visible = True
        Form_TimeCard.but_save.Top = 3540
        Select Case m_Day
            Case "Sunday"
                Form_TimeCard.but_save.Left = 1440
            Case "Monday"
                Form_TimeCard.but_save.Left = 2640
            Case "Tuesday"
                Form_TimeCard.but_save.Left = 3780
            Case "Wednesday"
                Form_TimeCard.but_save.Left = 4920
            Case "Thursday"
                Form_TimeCard.but_save.Left = 6060
            Case "Friday"
                Form_TimeCard.but_save.Left = 7200
            Case "Saturday"
                Form_TimeCard.but_save.Left = 8340
        End Select
    End If
End Sub
' Get control name
Public Property Get Name() As String
    Name = TC_txtbox.Name
End Property
' Get day of the week
Public Property Get Tag() As String
    Tag = TC_txtbox.Tag
End Property
' Save button was clicked
Public Sub Save()
    Dim ctl As Control
    Debug.Print "Day = " & m_Day
    For Each ctl In Form_TimeCard.Controls
        If m_Day = ctl.Tag Then
            Debug.Print ctl.Name & "=" & ctl.Tag
            ctl.BackColor = 16777215
            ctl.Locked = True
        End If
    Next ctl
    m_Day = ""
End Sub
' Get the data from the textbox
Public Function Value() As Variant
    Value = TC_txtbox.Value
End Function
```

Here is my main code

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit
' Global Variables
Private clk_inout As Boolean
Private settings As Dictionary
Private weekDict As Dictionary
Private weekOf As Variant
Private curDay As Variant
Private txtBxCollection As Collection

Private Sub but_save_Click()
    Dim ctl As TextBoxEventHandler
    Dim Day As String
    Dim dayDetail(1 To 7) As Variant
    Dim x As Integer
    x = 1

    Select Case Me.ActiveControl.Left
        Case 1440
            Day = "Sunday"
        Case 2640
            Day = "Monday"
        Case 3780
            Day = "Tuesday"
        Case 4920
            Day = "Wednesday"
        Case 6060
            Day = "Thursday"
        Case 7200
            Day = "Friday"
        Case 8340
            Day = "Saturday"
    End Select

    For Each ctl In txtBxCollection
        If ctl.Tag = Day Then
            Debug.Print ctl.Name
            dayDetail(x) = ctl.Value
            x = x + 1
            ctl.Save
        End If
    Next ctl
End Sub

' Event Handler for when the form opens
Private Sub Form_Open(Cancel As Integer)
    ' Configure varaibles
    Me.TimerInterval = 60000 ' 60 sec Interval
    weekOf = getFirstDayofWeek(Date)
    curDay = Date
    Set weekDict = New Dictionary
    Set settings = New Dictionary
    Set txtBxCollection = New Collection

    ' Load Time Card Data
    Call initSettings
    Debug.Print "Week Dict Count=" & weekDict.Count
    'Debug.Print "Work Day Goal " & settings.Item("Work_day_goal_hrs")
    Call initDict
    Call initTextBoxEventHandler
    Call loadDates(Date)
    Call clearDay
    Call selectDay(Date)
    Call loadWeeksData(weekOf)

    Dim ctl As Control
    Set ctl = weekDict.Item(Weekday(curDay)).Item("In")

    If IsDate(ctl.Value) And (Not ctl.Value = "") Then
        Me.but_clk_inout.Caption = "Clock Out"
        Me.but_lunch.Visible = True
        clk_inout = False
    Else
        Me.but_clk_inout.Caption = "Clock In"
        Me.but_lunch.Visible = False
        clk_inout = True
    End If
End Sub
' Regular task to be performed
Private Sub Form_Timer()
    If Not (curDay = Date) Then
        Call clearDay
        Call selectDay(Date)
    End If
    If Not (weekOf = getFirstDayofWeek(Date)) Then
        weekOf = getFirstDayofWeek(Date)
        Call loadDates(Date)
        Call loadWeeksData(Date)
    End If
    'Debug.Print "sal=" & settings.Item(1)
End Sub
' On Close of Form Insert/Update Time Card
Private Sub Form_Close()
    ' dump time card into database
    Set weekDict = Nothing
    Set settings = Nothing
End Sub
' Code for minimizing the window to the system tray
Private Sub Form_Load()
'    Debug.Print "HWND: " & Hex(GetWindowHWnd("OMain"))
'    Debug.Print "MENU: " & Hex(GetWindowSysMenu("OMain"))
'    AddToTray GetWindowHWnd("OMain"), GetWindowSysMenu("OMain")
'    SetTrayTip "Hollo World"
'    CreatePopup
'    ShowWindow GetWindowHWnd("OMain"), SW_HIDE
End Sub
Private Sub Form_Unload(Cancel As Integer)
'    RemoveFromTray GetWindowHWnd("OMain")
'    ShowWindow GetWindowHWnd("OMain"), SW_SHOW Or SW_RESTORE
'    DestroyMenu hMenu
End Sub
' Pop up form for configuring your settings
Private Sub but_settings_Click()
On Error GoTo EH
    Dim results As Variant
    Dim args As String
    args = "Settings|" & settings.Item("Salary") & "|" & _
                         settings.Item("Dental") & "|" & _
                         settings.Item("401k") & "|" & _
                         settings.Item("Federal") & "|" & _
                         settings.Item("Social_Security") & "|" & _
                         settings.Item("CT_tax") & "|" & _
                         settings.Item("Work_day_goal_hrs")

    results = settingsInputBox("Settings", settings)

    If Not results = vbNullString Then
        Debug.Print "Salary " & results(0)
        Debug.Print "Dental " & results(1)
        Debug.Print "Medical " & results(2)
        Debug.Print "401K " & results(3)
        Debug.Print "Federal Tax " & results(4)
    Else
        Debug.Print "Cancel button clicked"
    End If
EndIt:
    Exit Sub
EH:
    MsgBox Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description
    Resume EndIt
End Sub
' End system tray minimize code
' Clock inout button has been pressed
Private Sub but_clk_inout_Click()
    Dim inputTime As Variant
    Dim goal As Integer

    Select Case Me.but_clk_inout.Caption
        Case "Clock In"
            inputTime = InputBox("Enter Time", "Clock In")
            If (Not inputTime = "") And IsDate(inputTime) Then
                If Not dateExists(curDay) Then
                    'goal = settings.Item("Work_day_goal_hrs") ' Problem settings dictionary is no longer set
                    Me.txt_outGoal.Value = DateAdd("h", settings.Item("Work_day_goal_hrs"), "#" & inputTime & "#")
                    Me.but_clk_inout.Caption = "Clock Out"
                    Me.but_lunch.Visible = True
                    Me.lbl_outGoal.Visible = True
                    Me.txt_outGoal.Visible = True
                    Call logClkTime(True, inputTime)
                    clk_inout = True
                Else
                    MsgBox ("You already clocked in")
                    Exit Sub
                End If
            Else
                MsgBox ("Please enter a valid time")
                Exit Sub
            End If
        Case "Clock Out"
            inputTime = InputBox("Enter Time", "Clock Out")
            If Not inputTime = "" And IsDate(inputTime) Then
                Me.but_clk_inout.Caption = "Clock In"
                Me.but_lunch.Visible = False
                Call logClkTime(False, inputTime)
                clk_inout = False
            Else
                Exit Sub
            End If
        Case "Reset"
            If clk_inout Then
                Me.but_clk_inout.Caption = "Clock In"
            Else
                Me.but_clk_inout.Caption = "Clock Out"
            End If
            Call loadDates(Date)
            Call clearDay
            Call selectDay(Date)
            Call loadWeeksData(weekOf)
    End Select
End Sub
' Close Form
Private Sub but_close_Click()
    DoCmd.Close acForm, "TimeCard", acSaveYes
End Sub
' Find a time card already
Private Sub but_search_Click()
    Dim strSQL As String
    Dim dateInput As Variant
    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
    Dim dbs As DAO.Database
    Set dbs = CurrentDb()
    dateInput = Format(InputBox("Date XX/XX/XXXX", "Search by week"), "mm/dd/yyyy")

    If dateInput = "" Then
        MsgBox ("Please enter a valid date")
        Exit Sub
    ElseIf IsDate(dateInput) Then
        strSQL = "SELECT Week_Of FROM Time_Clock " & _
                 "WHERE (Labor_date=#" & dateInput & "# " & _
                 "OR Week_Of=#" & dateInput & "#);"

        Set rs = dbs.OpenRecordset(strSQL)

        If Not (rs.BOF And rs.EOF) Then
            rs.MoveLast
            rs.MoveFirst
            Dim pastWeek As Variant
            pastWeek = rs![Week_Of]
            Call loadDates(pastWeek)
            Call loadWeeksData(pastWeek)
            Call clearDay
            Me.but_clk_inout.Caption = "Reset"
        Else
            MsgBox ("Date does not exist")
        End If

        rs.Close
    Else
        MsgBox ("Invalid Date")
    End If
End Sub
' Data into week table
Public Sub loadWeeksData(wkDate As Variant)
    Dim weeklyHrs As Single
    Dim strSQL As String
    Dim dbs As DAO.Database
    Dim rs As Recordset
    Set dbs = CurrentDb()
    Dim ctl As Control

    weeklyHrs = 0
    strSQL = "SELECT * FROM Time_Clock " & _
             "WHERE Week_Of=" & Format("#" & wkDate & "#", "mm/dd/yyyy") & ";"
    Set rs = dbs.OpenRecordset(strSQL)

    If Not (rs.BOF And rs.EOF) Then
        Call clearTimeChart
        Do While Not rs.EOF
            weekDict(Weekday(rs![Labor_date]))("In").Value = Format(rs![Clock_In], "hh:mm ampm")
            'Set ctl = weekDict(Weekday(rs![Labor_date]))("In")
            'ctl.Value = Format(rs![Clock_In], "hh:mm ampm")
            weekDict(Weekday(rs![Labor_date]))("In").Value = Format(rs![Clock_In], "hh:mm ampm")
            weekDict(Weekday(rs![Labor_date]))("Lunch_Out").Value = rs![Lunch_out]
            weekDict(Weekday(rs![Labor_date]))("Lunch_in").Value = rs![Lunch_in]
            weekDict(Weekday(rs![Labor_date]))("Lunch_total").Value = rs![Lunch_total]

            If rs![Clock_Out] = #12:01:00 AM# And Not rs![Clock_In] = #12:00:00 AM# Then
                weekDict(Weekday(rs![Labor_date]))("Out").Value = rs![Clock_Out]
            Else
                weekDict(Weekday(rs![Labor_date]))("Out").Value = ""
            End If

            Debug.Print "(" & rs![Labor_date] & ") IN/OUT "; rs![Clock_In] & " / " & rs![Clock_Out]

            weekDict(Weekday(rs![Labor_date]))("Day_total").Value = rs![Total_Hours_Worked]
            weekDict(Weekday(rs![Labor_date]))("Paid_OT").Value = rs![Paid_OT]
            weeklyHrs = weeklyHrs + rs![Total_Hours_Worked]
            rs.MoveNext
        Loop
        Debug.Print "Weekly Hours " & weeklyHrs
    End If
End Sub
' Take Lunch Button Pressed
Private Sub but_lunch_Click()
    Dim strSQL As String
    If dateExists(curDay) Then
        strSQL = "UPDATE Time_Clock " & _
                 "SET Lunch_out=#11:30#, Lunch_in=12:00, Lunch_total=30 " & _
                 "WHERE Labor_date=#" & curDay & "#;"
        weekDict(Weekday(curDay))("Lunch_Out").Value = "11:30 AM"
        weekDict(Weekday(curDay))("Lunch_in").Value = "12:00 PM"
        weekDict(Weekday(curDay))("Lunch_total").Value = "30 mins"
    Else
        MsgBox ("Please clock in first before you take your lunch")
    End If
End Sub
' Load dates in each column
Public Sub loadDates(today As Variant)
    Me.txt_week_begin.Value = today - (Weekday(today) - 1)
    Me.txt_Sun_date.Value = today - (Weekday(today) - 1)
    Me.txt_M_date.Value = today - (Weekday(today) - 2)
    Me.txt_T_date.Value = today - (Weekday(today) - 3)
    Me.txt_W_date.Value = today - (Weekday(today) - 4)
    Me.txt_R_date.Value = today - (Weekday(today) - 5)
    Me.txt_F_date.Value = today - (Weekday(today) - 6)
    Me.txt_Sat_date.Value = today - (Weekday(today) - 7)
End Sub
Public Sub loadSettings()

End Sub
' Insert clock time into database
Public Sub logClkTime(inout As Boolean, clkTime As Variant)
    Dim strSQL As String
    Dim dbs As DAO.Database
    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
    Set dbs = CurrentDb()

    Select Case inout
        Case True  ' clock in
            strSQL = "INSERT INTO Time_Clock (Week_Of, Labor_date, Clock_In) " & _
                     "VALUES (#" & weekOf & "#, #" & curDay & "#, #" & Format(clkTime, "hh:mm") & "#);"
        Case False ' clock out
            Dim worked, worked_strt As Single
            Dim clkOut As Variant
            Dim clkIn As Variant
            clkOut = clkTime
            clkIn = weekDict.Item(Weekday(curDay)).Item("In").Value
            worked = DateDiff("h", clkIn, clkOut) + (DateDiff("n", clkIn, clkOut) - _
                    (DateDiff("h", clkIn, clkOut) * 60)) / 60
            worked_strt = Floor(worked)

            strSQL = "UPDATE Time_Clock (Clock_Out, Total_Hours_Worked, Straight_hours) " & _
                     "SET Clock_Out=#" & Format(clkTime, "hh:mm") & "#, Total_Hours_Worked=" & worked & ", Straight_hours=" & worked_strt & " " & _
                     "WHERE Labor_date=#" & curDay & "#;"
    End Select
    Debug.Print strSQL
    dbs.Execute (strSQL)
    dbs.Close
End Sub
' Has this date been logged into the database
Public Function dateExists(clkdDate As Variant) As Boolean
    Dim dbs As DAO.Database
    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
    Dim strSQL As String
    Set dbs = CurrentDb()

    If IsDate(clkdDate) Then
        strSQL = "SELECT ID FROM Time_Clock WHERE Labor_date=#" & clkdDate & "#;"
        Set rs = dbs.OpenRecordset(strSQL)
        If Not (rs.BOF And rs.EOF) Then
            If rs.RecordCount <> 0 Then
                Debug.Print "Date Exists"
                dateExists = True
            End If
        Else
            Debug.Print "Date Does Not Exists"
            dateExists = False
        End If
        rs.Close
    End If
    dbs.Close
End Function
' Draw a red box around the current day
Public Sub selectDay(today As Variant)
    Select Case Weekday(today)
        Case 1
            Me.rec_Sun.Visible = True
        Case 2
            Me.rec_M.Visible = True
        Case 3
            Me.rec_T.Visible = True
        Case 4
            Me.rec_W.Visible = True
        Case 5
            Me.rec_R.Visible = True
        Case 6
            Me.rec_F.Visible = True
        Case 7
            Me.rec_Sat.Visible = True
    End Select
End Sub
' Clear the current day selection box
Public Sub clearDay()
    Me.rec_Sun.Visible = False
    Me.rec_Sat.Visible = False
    Me.rec_M.Visible = False
    Me.rec_T.Visible = False
    Me.rec_W.Visible = False
    Me.rec_R.Visible = False
    Me.rec_F.Visible = False
End Sub
' Clear data from time Chart
Public Sub clearTimeChart()
    Dim arr As Variant
    arr = Array("In", "Lunch_Out", "Lunch_in", "Lunch_total", "Out", "Day_total", "Paid_OT")
    Dim x, y As Integer
    For x = 1 To 7
        For y = 0 To 6
            weekDict.Item(x).Item(arr(y)).Value = ""
        Next
    Next
End Sub
' Initialize the weekly time chart control dictionary
Public Sub initDict()
    Dim dayDict

    Set dayDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    dayDict.Add "In", Me.txt_Sun_in
    dayDict.Add "Lunch_Out", Me.txt_Sun_LO
    dayDict.Add "Lunch_in", Me.txt_Sun_LI
    dayDict.Add "Lunch_total", Me.txt_Sun_LT
    dayDict.Add "Out", Me.txt_Sun_out
    dayDict.Add "Day_total", Me.txt_Sun_out
    dayDict.Add "Paid_OT", Me.txt_Sun_OT
    weekDict.Add 1, dayDict
    Set dayDict = Nothing

    Set dayDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    dayDict.Add "In", Me.txt_M_in
    dayDict.Add "Lunch_Out", Me.txt_M_LO
    dayDict.Add "Lunch_in", Me.txt_M_LI
    dayDict.Add "Lunch_total", Me.txt_M_LT
    dayDict.Add "Out", Me.txt_M_out
    dayDict.Add "Day_total", Me.txt_M_out
    dayDict.Add "Paid_OT", Me.txt_M_OT
    weekDict.Add 2, dayDict
    Set dayDict = Nothing

    Set dayDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    dayDict.Add "In", Me.txt_T_in
    dayDict.Add "Lunch_Out", Me.txt_T_LO
    dayDict.Add "Lunch_in", Me.txt_T_LI
    dayDict.Add "Lunch_total", Me.txt_T_LT
    dayDict.Add "Out", Me.txt_T_out
    dayDict.Add "Day_total", Me.txt_T_out
    dayDict.Add "Paid_OT", Me.txt_T_OT
    weekDict.Add 3, dayDict
    Set dayDict = Nothing

    Set dayDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    dayDict.Add "In", Me.txt_W_in
    dayDict.Add "Lunch_Out", Me.txt_W_LO
    dayDict.Add "Lunch_in", Me.txt_W_LI
    dayDict.Add "Lunch_total", Me.txt_W_LT
    dayDict.Add "Out", Me.txt_W_out
    dayDict.Add "Day_total", Me.txt_W_out
    dayDict.Add "Paid_OT", Me.txt_W_OT
    weekDict.Add 4, dayDict
    Set dayDict = Nothing

    Set dayDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    dayDict.Add "In", Me.txt_R_in
    dayDict.Add "Lunch_Out", Me.txt_R_LO
    dayDict.Add "Lunch_in", Me.txt_R_LI
    dayDict.Add "Lunch_total", Me.txt_R_LT
    dayDict.Add "Out", Me.txt_R_out
    dayDict.Add "Day_total", Me.txt_R_out
    dayDict.Add "Paid_OT", Me.txt_R_OT
    weekDict.Add 5, dayDict
    Set dayDict = Nothing

    Set dayDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    dayDict.Add "In", Me.txt_F_in
    dayDict.Add "Lunch_Out", Me.txt_F_LO
    dayDict.Add "Lunch_in", Me.txt_F_LI
    dayDict.Add "Lunch_total", Me.txt_F_LT
    dayDict.Add "Out", Me.txt_F_out
    dayDict.Add "Day_total", Me.txt_F_out
    dayDict.Add "Paid_OT", Me.txt_F_OT
    weekDict.Add 6, dayDict
    Set dayDict = Nothing

    Set dayDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    dayDict.Add "In", Me.txt_Sat_in
    dayDict.Add "Lunch_Out", Me.txt_Sat_LO
    dayDict.Add "Lunch_in", Me.txt_Sat_LI
    dayDict.Add "Lunch_total", Me.txt_Sat_LT
    dayDict.Add "Out", Me.txt_Sat_out
    dayDict.Add "Day_total", Me.txt_Sat_out
    dayDict.Add "Paid_OT", Me.txt_Sat_OT
    weekDict.Add 7, dayDict
    Set dayDict = Nothing
End Sub
' Load settings into dictionary
Public Sub initSettings()
    Dim strSQL As String
    Dim dbs As DAO.Database
    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
    Set dbs = CurrentDb()

    strSQL = "SELECT * FROM Settings WHERE ID=1;"
    Set rs = dbs.OpenRecordset(strSQL)
    If Not (rs.BOF And rs.EOF) Then
        If rs.RecordCount <> 0 Then
            settings.Add 1, rs![Salary]
            settings.Add 2, rs![Dental]
            settings.Add 3, rs![401K]
            settings.Add 4, rs![Federal]
            settings.Add 5, rs![Social_Security]
            settings.Add 6, rs![Medicare]
            settings.Add 7, rs![CT_tax]
            settings.Add 8, rs![Work_day_goal_hrs]
        End If
    Else
        Debug.Print "No Settings!"
    End If
End Sub
' Get the control by object name
Public Function getControl(ByVal ctlName As String) As Control
    Dim ctl As Control
    For Each ctl In Me.Controls
        If ctl.Name = ctlName Then
            Set getControl = ctl
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next ctl
End Function

Public Sub initTextBoxEventHandler()
    Dim eventHandler As TextBoxEventHandler
    Set eventHandler = New TextBoxEventHandler

    Set eventHandler.TextBox = Me.txt_Sun_in
    txtBxCollection.Add eventHandler
    Set eventHandler = Nothing
    Set eventHandler = New TextBoxEventHandler
    Set eventHandler.TextBox = Me.txt_Sun_LO
    txtBxCollection.Add eventHandler
    Set eventHandler = Nothing
    Set eventHandler = New TextBoxEventHandler
    Set eventHandler.TextBox = Me.txt_Sun_LI
    txtBxCollection.Add eventHandler
    Set eventHandler = Nothing
    Set eventHandler = New TextBoxEventHandler
    Set eventHandler.TextBox = Me.txt_Sun_out
    txtBxCollection.Add eventHandler
    Set eventHandler = Nothing
    Set eventHandler = New TextBoxEventHandler

    Set eventHandler.TextBox = Me.txt_M_in
    txtBxCollection.Add eventHandler
    Set eventHandler = Nothing
    Set eventHandler = New TextBoxEventHandler
    Set eventHandler.TextBox = Me.txt_M_LO
    txtBxCollection.Add eventHandler
    Set eventHandler = Nothing
    Set eventHandler = New TextBoxEventHandler
    Set eventHandler.TextBox = Me.txt_M_LI
    txtBxCollection.Add eventHandler
    Set eventHandler = Nothing
    Set eventHandler = New TextBoxEventHandler
    Set eventHandler.TextBox = Me.txt_M_out
    txtBxCollection.Add eventHandler
    Set eventHandler = Nothing
    Set eventHandler = New TextBoxEventHandler

    Set eventHandler.TextBox = Me.txt_T_in
    txtBxCollection.Add eventHandler
    Set eventHandler = Nothing
    Set eventHandler = New TextBoxEventHandler
    Set eventHandler.TextBox = Me.txt_T_LO
    txtBxCollection.Add eventHandler
    Set eventHandler = Nothing
    Set eventHandler = New TextBoxEventHandler
    Set eventHandler.TextBox = Me.txt_T_LI
    txtBxCollection.Add eventHandler
    Set eventHandler = Nothing
    Set eventHandler = New TextBoxEventHandler
    Set eventHandler.TextBox = Me.txt_T_out
    txtBxCollection.Add eventHandler
    Set eventHandler = Nothing
    Set eventHandler = New TextBoxEventHandler

    Set eventHandler.TextBox = Me.txt_W_in
    txtBxCollection.Add eventHandler
    Set eventHandler = Nothing
    Set eventHandler = New TextBoxEventHandler
    Set eventHandler.TextBox = Me.txt_W_LO
    txtBxCollection.Add eventHandler
    Set eventHandler = Nothing
    Set eventHandler = New TextBoxEventHandler
    Set eventHandler.TextBox = Me.txt_W_LI
    txtBxCollection.Add eventHandler
    Set eventHandler = Nothing
    Set eventHandler = New TextBoxEventHandler
    Set eventHandler.TextBox = Me.txt_W_out
    txtBxCollection.Add eventHandler
    Set eventHandler = Nothing
    Set eventHandler = New TextBoxEventHandler

    Set eventHandler.TextBox = Me.txt_R_in
    txtBxCollection.Add eventHandler
    Set eventHandler = Nothing
    Set eventHandler = New TextBoxEventHandler
    Set eventHandler.TextBox = Me.txt_R_LO
    txtBxCollection.Add eventHandler
    Set eventHandler = Nothing
    Set eventHandler = New TextBoxEventHandler
    Set eventHandler.TextBox = Me.txt_R_LI
    txtBxCollection.Add eventHandler
    Set eventHandler = Nothing
    Set eventHandler = New TextBoxEventHandler
    Set eventHandler.TextBox = Me.txt_R_out
    txtBxCollection.Add eventHandler
    Set eventHandler = Nothing
    Set eventHandler = New TextBoxEventHandler

    Set eventHandler.TextBox = Me.txt_F_in
    txtBxCollection.Add eventHandler
    Set eventHandler = Nothing
    Set eventHandler = New TextBoxEventHandler
    Set eventHandler.TextBox = Me.txt_F_LO
    txtBxCollection.Add eventHandler
    Set eventHandler = Nothing
    Set eventHandler = New TextBoxEventHandler
    Set eventHandler.TextBox = Me.txt_F_LI
    txtBxCollection.Add eventHandler
    Set eventHandler = Nothing
    Set eventHandler = New TextBoxEventHandler
    Set eventHandler.TextBox = Me.txt_F_out
    txtBxCollection.Add eventHandler
    Set eventHandler = Nothing
    Set eventHandler = New TextBoxEventHandler

    Set eventHandler.TextBox = Me.txt_Sat_in
    txtBxCollection.Add eventHandler
    Set eventHandler = Nothing
    Set eventHandler = New TextBoxEventHandler
    Set eventHandler.TextBox = Me.txt_Sat_LO
    txtBxCollection.Add eventHandler
    Set eventHandler = Nothing
    Set eventHandler = New TextBoxEventHandler
    Set eventHandler.TextBox = Me.txt_Sat_LI
    txtBxCollection.Add eventHandler
    Set eventHandler = Nothing
    Set eventHandler = New TextBoxEventHandler
    Set eventHandler.TextBox = Me.txt_Sat_out
    txtBxCollection.Add eventHandler
    Set eventHandler = Nothing
    Set eventHandler = New TextBoxEventHandler
    Set eventHandler = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: I *think* I understand this question a bit but not enough to answer. You have created a special class to handle the event of a textbox, and because you have multiple textboxes, you have created a collection of objects that are instances of this class? That's a valid technique sometimes. But I don't understand what an "extended" textbox is and nor do I understand "calling its form name". Can you post some code, or perhaps the code is too long to post? Anyway, you might be interested in this article about dealing with arrays of objects that raise events http://vb.mvps.org/articles/ap200008.asp

Comment: Extended just means that I am add more functionality to the control object kind of internal versus externally

Comment: Are you programming in VBA within Access or in VB6? The answer to your question will be completely different depending on which you're using. I'm assuming you're actually using Access and programming in VBA, and with that in mind, it sounds to me like you should be using a continuous form, since it seems like you have a number of repeating controls in columns. In that case, you don't have to change all of them, as each is an instance of a single control.

Comment: I am using vba in access.  I am still pretty new with vba only been programming it for about a week and a half

Comment: I forgot to add that I am creating a time card application in access where the form uses has 7 columns with about 8 rows to display the weeks clock in/out, lunch in/out, OT and total hours.  you can enter search for a previous week and it will clear the current time card matrix and inserted the found data into it.  The part I am asking help for is when a user clicks a textbox to enabling editing its contents.

Comment: I've removed the VB6 tag, as it was just confusing things.

Comment: Do you know how to use a continuous form?

Comment: Nope.  I was thinking I could probably use a global variable and pass it by reference into my event handlers

Comment: You should look at continuous forms. I don't think you need all this complicated code at all, with or without global variables and event handlers. Then again, you've not really fully explained what you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

Hallo,

It was nice to see your all project - I agree with MarkJ - who said that - in VBA there is no possibility to use events in arrays and also in collection - with collections and events I don't have too much experience - but I read about it - about arrays - I spent whole night - and discovered that VBA is not C++ :( . Try to show all project. Norbert

Comment: Have you not given continuous forms a look? It would likely eliminate almost all of your code while providing nearly all the same functionality.